# How to get the information about my USB bus, version on Android 9

Tags: usb

On my Android 5 the app Device Info HW shows what version of USB I have and whatnot, on my Android 9 the info is blank, why?

Is there any other way to check it somehow?

Comment: May be the used USB chip is unknown to the app or it is no longer possible to access those info on newer Android devices.

Comment: Seems there's a lot of things that are impossible to access in Android 9! Any way without an app?